# Angular does not update after updating variable in component

Tags: angular

I use Angular 9 and modify a variable that I use in a template. But unfortunately my template does not get updated. Can anyone explain me what the typical approach is to let Angular know that something in my component changed?

```js
projects: any[] = [];
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.actRoute.params.subscribe((params) => {
        this.electronService.foo.bar(
        .then((x) => {
            var history = x.y();

            history.on("begin", () => {
                this.projects.push('foo');
            });
            history.execute();
        });
    });
}
```

**foo.component.html**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let project of projects;">{{project}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular will not detect the changes if you don't change the "in memory" variable. In your case, just pushing the same variable will not trigget the change detection. You should `this.projects = this.projects.slice()` or something like that to change the memory variable and trigger the change. If that doesn't fit you, there are other things you can use like Injecting `ChangeDetector` then calling `ChangeDetector.detectChanges();`

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

...
this.projects.push('foo');
this.cd.detectChanges();
...
```

Comment: I don't know who downvoted your post, but it works! Thank you so much. Is there anything seen to be as a side effect?

Comment: The side effect is that the changedetector trigger the change from the view in a whole. So if you have too many inputs or interpolations on your page on the moment, it will cost some performance. Changing in memory variable has no cost at all. Not that I know.

Comment: I have an `end` event as well, so I don't trigger `detectChanges` for every event. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the arrow function. `this` doesn't have the same meaning as you think it does

```js
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    let projects = this.projects;
    projects = [];

    this.actRoute.params.subscribe((params) => {
        this.electronService.foo.bar(
          .then((x) => { // arrow function
            const history = x.y(); // use const

            history.on("begin", () => { // arrow function
              projects.push('foo');
            });
            history.execute();
          });
        });
    }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! That explains actually a lot now in my code. However, changing the code still doesn't update the Angular view :-/. Is this maybe caused due to the event handlers where Angular doesn't notice any changes?

Comment: Could be something in your `electronService`. Make sure you're using arrow functions there as well

Comment: Thanks! I verified that it gets properly executed. If I "manually" refresh the "page" the entries are visible. It seems to me the change is done outside Angulars zone, but don't know how I can make Angular aware of that change

Comment: import `ChangeDetectorRef` and then run `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` after your update. But, I would recommend debugging that further to figure out the actual problem rather than implement the "workaround". Sounds like your problem revolved around the lifecycle hook or scope.